# How to enable TRIM?

Tags: ssd, trim

I know that the Linux kernel supports TRIM as of version 2.6.33, so there should be TRIM support in ubuntu.

Is TRIM enabled by default or do I need to change some settings or install additional software for it to work? If so, how?

Comment: I just followed these instructions on webupd8 which gives some really good options :-) http://www.webupd8.org/2013/01/enable-trim-on-ssd-solid-state-drives.html I tried the option for automatic trim as described above in "Automatic TRIM"
but found that setting up a daily cron worked alot better with my setup.

Answer (score 205, accepted):

## Ubuntu 14.10 onwards

In Ubuntu 14.10 and 15.04, TRIMming happens automatically every week on all SSDs supported by `fstrim`.

```
$ tail -n1 /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim 
/sbin/fstrim --all || true
```

Since 15.04 Ubuntu uses systemd and its timer (`man systemd.timer`, [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers))

```
systemctl list-timers
systemctl status fstrim.timer
```

## Ubuntu 14.04

As of Ubuntu 14.04, scheduled TRIM is **enabled by default for Intel, SAMSUNG, OCZ, Patriot and Sandisk SSDs.** If you have another brand, you could disable the vendor check by running the following command:

```
sed -i 's/exec fstrim-all/exec fstrim-all --no-model-check/g' /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

(or just edit the file `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim` and add `--no-model-check`)

## Ubuntu 13.10 and Earlier

There are three ways to perform TRIM, manual, scheduled, and automatic:

### Manual TRIM

In Ubuntu this can be performed with [`fstrim`](http://manpg.es/fstrim):

```
sudo fstrim /
```

however it is not needed when scheduled or automatic TRIM are enabled, as detailed in the sections below.

*Note:* For **Ubuntu 11.04** and earlier systems, fstrim is not available so you have to use `wiper.sh` supplied with `hdparm` in `/usr/share/doc/hdparm/contrib/wiper.sh.gz`

### Scheduled TRIM (Recommended)

This is the currently recomended method, and is [planed to be activated per default for Ubuntu 14.04](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/core-1311-ssd-trimming). Here's how to activate it manually in older versions of ubuntu (11.10 to 13.10):

Create a weekly CRON job script file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

Paste the following code in the file, then save and close the file:

```
#! /bin/sh  

# By default we assume only / is on an SSD. 
# You can add more SSD mount points, separated by spaces.
# Make sure all mount points are within the quotes. For example:
# SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/ /boot /home /media/my_other_ssd'  

SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/'  

for mount_point in $SSD_MOUNT_POINTS
do  
    fstrim $mount_point  
done
```

Note that the above assumes that only your root filesystem `/` is located on an SSD. If you have more mount points that reside on one or more SSDs, add them to `SSD_MOUNT_POINTS` as explained in the code.

Make the script executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

And finally test it:

```
sudo /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim
```

If you see no errors, your cron job should be working fine.

### Automatic TRIM (Deprecated, Slow)

Automatic TRIM has been supported since Ubuntu 10.10 (kernel 2.6.33) with the EXT4 file system. However, sending TRIM commands to the SSD in real-time - after every delete - has been recognized to make deletion much slower than usual on some drives. Therefore a weekly scheduled TRIM via a cron job (described above) is recomended.

To enable automatic TRIM on a drive or partition, they need to be mounted with the `discard` option in `fstab`. Firstly backup your fstab then open it for editing:

```
sudo cp /etc/fstab ~/fstab-backup
gksudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

Add `discard` to the fstab options entry (comma separated) for the SSD drive or each partition.

```
UUID=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000  /  ext4  discard,errors=remount-ro  0  1
```

Close and save fstab, then reboot and automatic TRIM should now be working.

#### Testing automatic TRIM

To test if TRIM is working issue the following commands ([source](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?63843-The-truth-about-firmware-1.4-and-Linux&p=479503&viewfull=1#post479503)):

```
cd  / # Replace with SSD file system
sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=tempfile count=100 bs=512k oflag=direct
sudo hdparm --fibmap tempfile
```

From the output copy the number under `begin_LBA` and verify the device name of your SSD: `System->Administration->Disk Utility` e.g. *sda, sdb, sdc* ...

Run the following but replace `[ADDRESS]` (begin_LBA) and `sdX` (SSD device name) with the details obtained above.

```
sudo hdparm --read-sector [ADDRESS] /dev/sdX
```

the output should be a long string of characters for those sectors

```
sudo rm tempfile
sync
```

Repeat the `hdparm` command from above:

```
sudo hdparm --read-sector [ADDRESS] /dev/sdX
```

If you get only zeros then automatic TRIM is working. However if after removing the file the sectors are still not empty then wait a while and run the command again.

Comment: Testing TRIM may not actually work like that: http://serverfault.com/a/401506/60525

Comment: @Uli Please someone help me. It doesnt seem to work for me. I have 4 partitions in my ssd `/` `/boot` `/usr` and `/opt` and I have used another hdd for my `/home`. I go to `cd / #sdc` and I continue with the instructions but I never get zeros. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @GeoPapas Are you sure your SSD supports TRIM? You might also be experiencing the issue linked to in the comment above yours.

Comment: @Uli It supports TRIM. Does it have to do with journaling on/off ? I have it enabled with ext4. In the comment i cant see any solution. I remember that i never had any issues with enabling TRIM in the past on the same ssd. I ll check `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/discard_zeroes_data` and see what i can find out...

Comment: @lightrush: Great edit! Thanks for keeping the answer up to date.

Comment: I should update my blog post too. Quite a few people end up there. :)

Comment: You might want to add a `sync` after the `dd` command, since at least on my system the tempfile is not created right away, so hdparm reports nothing.

Comment: feel free to edit ;-)

Comment: According to http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/trusty/util-linux/trusty/view/head:/debian/fstrim-all fstrim-all will also work for **OCZ,
Patriot** and **Sandisk** and is automatically activated on Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (See /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim)

Comment: Note: "System->Administration->Disk Utility" means launch the "Disks" application from the Unity Dash.  From this utility, make a note of the device name of your SSD (e.g. sda, sdb, sdc ...).  The value to use in [ADDRESS] should be the first begin_LBA number listed (with a byte_offset = 0) after executing "sudo hdparm --fibmap tempfile".

Comment: after i upgrade to ssd and upgrade distro to 17.10 i decide to check and there is no fstrim file in /etc/cron.weekly, do i have to create it manually, and what is the correct code to add inside?

Comment: systemd handles this now. sudo systemctl status fstrim.timer

Answer (score 29):

Note that if you are using encryption the solutions posted here so far won't help you, because you need to enable TRIM support in the encryption layer as well. This can be done with kernel versions 3.1+ and cryptsetup versions 1.4+, both of which are included in Ubuntu 12.04.

Find my guide on setting TRIM up for LUKS encrypted partitions [here](http://worldsmostsecret.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-activate-trim-on-luks-encrypted.html)

---

How to Activate TRIM on LUKS Encrypted Partitions in Ubuntu & Debian

---

This step by step walkthrough will let you take advantage of the TRIM technology for your encrypted SSD partitions for cryptsetup 1.4 or higher and kernel 3.1 or higher. This leads to a hassle-free SSD experience because

> "TRIM enables the SSD to handle garbage collection overhead, that
>   would otherwise significantly slow down future write operations to the
>   involved blocks, in advance."

**Example Setup**

Notebook with SSD as the single drive, Linux installed in single ext4 LVM root partition with LVM swap partition, both over LUKS encrypted logical partition.

SSD: /dev/sda

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
/dev/sda1               # boot partition (83) (unencrypted, ext4)
/dev/sda2               # extended partition
/dev/sda5               # logical partition (83) with LUKS encryption

ls /dev/mapper
/dev/mapper/sda5_crypt         # encrypted LUKS device in physical /dev/sda5 partition
/dev/mapper/volumegroup-root   # rootpartition sda5_crypt
/dev/mapper/volumegroup-swap   # swap partition sda5_crypt
```

**HowTo**

1. Make a backup of all your data. You're messing with your file system
   so having a backup is simply a good idea.
2. Make sure you have the required kernel and cryptsetup versions (3.1
   & 1.4, e.g. in Ubuntu 12.04, beware though, at time of writing 12.04
   is still beta).
3. Add discard parameter to the file system options of the encrypted
   LVM volume(s) in your /etc/fstab file. This makes the file system of
   your LVM partition aware that you want to use TRIM.

   ```
   /dev/mapper/volumegroup-root    /   ext4 discard,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro    0    1
   ```
4. The last step is not enough though. As long as LUKS is not aware
   that you want to use TRIM it will effectively block all TRIM
   operations coming from the LVM partition's file system, for security
   reasons. Add discard parameter to the cryptdevice options in
   /etc/crypttab to make LUKS accept the discard behavior of the LVM
   partition.

   ```
   sda5_crypt UUID=e364d03f-[...]6cd7e none luks,discard
   ```
5. Rebuild your initramfs. The crypttab options are stored there and
   used on boot.

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
   ```
6. Reboot.
7. Check if TRIM is now active.

   ```
   sudo dmsetup table /dev/mapper/sda5_crypt --showkeys
   ```
8. If the last command shows a result like this (1 allow_discards at the end) you're all set.

   ```
   0  77656056  crypt  aes-cbc-essiv:sha256  abc[...]c7a0c  0  8:5  2056  1  allow_discards
   ```

**Result**

TRIM is activated. Enjoy your hassle-free SSD!

Comment: @Marco Ceppi any specific reason for the edit, something I overlooked?

Comment: Just [tidying up the markdown and removed the "signature" line](http://askubuntu.com/posts/122007/revisions) (it's assumed that you'll get feedback via comments and voting on the site.

Comment: The guide should be included here in case that site/page is unavailable.

Comment: Besides that this is effectively a link-only answer, it's not working at all. Most of you will use LVM with LUKS, which isn't capable of propagating TRIM in 12.04. See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/191945/88802) for more info.

Comment: After following these instructions, is it still necessary to set up a cron job to trim the disk on 14.04?

Comment: Notice: enabling TRIM on an encrypted partition reduces the security of the encryption because it reveals which parts of the partition contain data and which don't. This can aid in some types of analysis. To put this in perspective this does not immediately make your data visible but  it would be a similar security trade-off to using a sparse file as the encrypted block, or of setting up an encrypted partition but not initialising the free space with random data, as is usually recommended.

Comment: @Is TRIM still needed with SSDs (with LVM & LUKS) nowadays?