# SSD + TRIM + ext4 OK. What about LVM and RAID?

Tags: raid, ext4, ssd, lvm, trim

I've read that SSD TRIM is now supported in the recent kernels with ext4 too (see [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim) ).

Is it OK/safe to enable TRIM when having
a) LVM
b) RAID1+LVM?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Device Mapper based RAID `e.g. via dmsetup` **does support TRIM** MD raid `e.g. via mdadm` **does not support TRIM**.

http://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2010-October/msg00066.html

This might have changed, but a quick grep of the oneiric kernel `(git grep REQ_DISCARD drivers/md)`doesn't show any specific support in the MD code for discards. It might be worth searching the MD RAID mailing list to see how this has progressed.

Speaking from experience, I am not a big fan of using DM for managing RAID sets, the tools are kinda cumbersome and basic admin tasks are a burden; and so is recovering a failed RAID. If you want to take the plunge I strongly recommend you model the setup in a VM so you can become accustomed with the toolset's ins and outs. BTW, don't get confused by `dmraid`, that's for *fake raid only*.

http://mbroz.fedorapeople.org/talks/DeviceMapperBasics/dm.pdf