# How do I enable Trim on an SSD in a Wubi install under Windows 7?

Tags: wubi, ssd

I've installed Wubi on an SSD on a  Windows 7 x64 system. Wubi and Windows 7 reside on the same ntfs formated drive/partition. How does trim work for this configuration? How do I configure it? Everything I've seen refer to a direct install of Ubuntu on an ext4 formated drive etc.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim

Answer (score 3):

Installing Ubuntu with [Wubi](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Improving_disk_performance) creates a container file (`root.disk`) that occupies the full size you specified on your NTFS Windows partition. As soon as you boot Wubi-Ubuntu, it loop mounts a virtual hard disk within the `root.disk` container file and boots from it. *Note that* when you delete files in this virtual hard disk, the free space *cannot be seen by Windows TRIM* because the `root.disk` container file still occupies the full specified size.

Thus, TRIM would be only enabled when writing data to `root.disk` from Windows, but as explained Wubi does not do that. Files are written to this container from Ubuntu. Therefore the TRIM functionality of Windows will have no effect here.

> We can not enable TRIM for write access from Ubuntu booted with Wubi.<sup>[Source](http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/wubi-ssd-und-trim/)</sup>

Therefore you should seriously consider installing Ubuntu as [dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) if possible, if you are running from an SSD.