# SSD tweaks for Ubuntu 12.04 cause Texmaker to compile a lot slower

Tags: 12.04, performance, ssd, latex, trim

I added these tweaks from [Ubuntu SSD Tweak](http://www.richud.com/wiki/Ubuntu_SSD_Tweak) and [Ubuntu Tweaks](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/250-ubuntu-tweaks-ssd) but now Texmaker is compiling slowly.  Does someone know what tweak would be causing this?  Or could I edit something unrelated to the tweaks to get Texmaker to compile as it did previously?

2nd Gen intel i5, 16GB Cosair ram, 240GB Cosair Force series GT, NTFS, quick build LaTex to PDF

Comment: In case you don't get a suitable answer here, consider asking at http://tex.stackexchange.com/ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both guides you link to have you enable the `discard` mount option for your filesystem. In my experience, this kills performance. On every sync after a file has been deleted, a TRIM request gets sent, causing the disk to freeze up for 2 to 3 seconds. (This will be hardware-dependent.)

To see whether this is the problem, try testing `fsync` performance as suggested [in this thread](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/linux/kernel/1059422#1059422):

> Running Theodore Ts'os "fsync-tester" while doing Linus' torture test
>
> ```
> while : ; do time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=bigfile bs=8M count=256 ; sync; rm bigfile"; done
> ```
>
> shows it clearly

Sync should be fast on an SSD. In my case and that poster's case, each sync causes a lockup of several seconds. See also https://patrick-nagel.net/blog/archives/337 for a similar example.

If you see similar behavior, you should disable automatic TRIM by removing the `discard` option from your fstab. (But keep the `noatime` or `relatime` option that you probably added.)

Instead, periodically run `fstrim` on your filesystem, e.g. using `cron`. Several ways to do this are given in [this article](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd#TOC-Automatic-TRIM%3a-by-rc.local-by-cron-or-by-discard). This way you should still get the benefits of TRIM without the performance problems.