# How to enable the trim on Transcend 320 Ultra-fast 256GB SSD?

Tags: ssd, trim

I got a new TS256GSSD320, I'd like to put on the trim.

I have edited `/etc/fstab` with `discard` on the boot  partition but the trim is still off.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it should had worled.  please see this answer that explains more about ssd on ubuntu.  Link: [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)

Comment: I did the procedure already but it s not working

Comment: sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM
    * Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 1 block)
    * Deterministic read data after TRIM