# Is TRIM on by default in 13.04?

Tags: ssd, trim

I've just installed the Ubuntu Raring (with Sandisk Extreme) and I know there're multiple articles over the internet (and here) about TRIM, but I suspect it's a native resource on Ubuntu Raring.

PS: Tried to find something in the Ubuntu's documentation, but did not.

Then I've read lots (and lots) of articles and all of them providing different ways to enable TRIM (fstab, cron job, init scripts, etc ..).

IE: [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)

And I got something interesting -> I've performed those tests (creating testfile / removing / running hdparm) WITHOUT "discard" in the /etc/fstab and I got that same results, I got those expected "zeros" output.

That suggested TRIM test I've uploaded (just in case), http://www.pasteall.org/43964/text

That's why I'm wondering -> Is the TRIM active by default on Ubuntu Raring?

If not .. any recommended way to active it, among so much options? Thx.

PS: This is not the same question as the duplicated one. Here I'm trying to understand the NATIVE trim support (as it looks like)

Comment: Thx Jorge, I didn't notice :)

Comment: Luis Alvarado, you marked it as duplicated, but that is the exact link I provided .. not sure if you understand my point. WITHOUT adding "discard" to fstab, I got the same result.. got it?

Answer (score 1):

Having recently bought a SSD I made some tests to understand the native Ubuntu support for SSD/TRIM.

I followed the following instructions ([source](https://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/checkiftrimonext4isenabledandworking))

```
sudo -i
dd if=/dev/urandom of=tempfile count=100 bs=512k oflag=direct
hdparm --fibmap tempfile
```

Note the first LBA

```
hdparm --read-sector FIRST_LBA /dev/sdX
```

Replace `FIRST_LBA` with the number found with `--fibmap` and `/dev/sdX` with the device name (probably `sda`).

You should get a set of numbers. If you get all zeros you are doing something wrong and you are probably reading the wrong segment or device.

At this point remove the file and check again.

```
rm tempfile
sync
hdparm --read-sector FIRST_LBA /dev/sdX
```

If TRIM is enabled you should get mostly zeros, if not you should get the same series of number than before.

So, to answer your question, if this test is to be belived **Ubuntu is not supporting TRIM by default**.

Personally I add `discard` to the fstab options, but many prefers to run `fstrim` from a cronjob, but this is covered by other threads/answers.