# TRIM and encrypted home folders

Tags: encryption, home-directory, ssd, trim

I have enabled TRIM for my root partition by adding `discard` in `/etc/fstab`, following [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim/19480#19480)

They mention that special steps are needed if I have an encrypted partition. I have encrypted folders, but not encrypted partitions.

Do encrypted home folders need special steps to enable TRIM?

Comment: `/home` is a partition, so if you've chosen to encrypt your home directory I think you do have an encrypted partition. Maybe someone more knowledgeable can clarify?

Comment: `/home` is not a partition on my laptop - it is a directory in the root partition. I do not have a separate home partition. My user's home directory is a subdirectory of `/home`, i.e. it's `/home/satuon`. Also, home directories are encrypted on a per-user basis. For example, I have another user whose home directory is not encrypted. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome.

Comment: If your `/home` is encrypted, Ubuntu still treats it very similar to a different partition, so if people refer to it as a partition, do not be surprised.

Answer (score 0):

*In bash:*

```
if [ -e /etc/crypttab ] ; then
  echo "Yes, you do!"
else
  echo "No, you don't..."
fi
```

*In human:*

If you have a `/etc/crypttab` file on your system, yes you need to do something "special" to your encrypted folders to allow TRIM!