# How to use TRIM on encrypted home folder

Tags: encryption, ssd, home-directory, ecryptfs, trim

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. During the installation, I've checked 'encrypted home' but home folder is in the same partition as the root (i.e in '/'). I know that the usage of TRIM on LUKS devices is different but I could not find anything about how to use it in my case. I also know that the installer uses ecryptfs for home folder encryption. The only thing I could found is this link [TRIM and encrypted home folders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338579/trim-and-encrypted-home-folders), but it does not provide an answer. So the question is: How can I use TRIM on my encrypted home folder (not partition)? Several info you might need:

SSD: Corsair Force LS SSD

```
~$ lsblk
NAME           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda              8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk  
├─sda1           8:1    0   512M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2           8:2    0 215.2G  0 part  /
└─sda3           8:3    0   7.9G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap1 252:0    0   7.9G  0 crypt [SWAP]

~$ uname -r
4.4.0-21-generic
```

Comment: Why do you want to use trim ? Ubuntu > 14.04 trims the disk automatically.  (See: `/etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`)

Comment: /home/username doesn't support trim. It's enough to trim root which contains /home encrypted files

Answer (score 0):

Encrypted home folder are virtualy mounted unencrypted.

All your files in your encrypted /home/username 
folder exist real in:/home/.ecryptfs/username 
in encrypted format.

So if you use "fstrim -av" you are trimming the complete disk unneeded.

```
~$ fstrim -av
/home/username: 271.1 GiB (291104260096 bytes) trimmed
/: 0 B (0 bytes) trimmed
```

After every reboot it will do the same.

So it is better to trimm only the real files written on disk:

```
fstrim -v /
```

Add a weekly scheduler:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/fstrim.{service,timer} /etc/systemd/system
sudo systemctl enable fstrim.timer
```

and edit /etc/systemd/system/fstrim.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Discard unused blocks

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/fstrim -v /
```