# Unable to get TRIM to work on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ssd, trim

I am trying to use the fstrim command on my machine. The configuration is as follows :

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-10-56:~/test$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
```

And I have created the fstrim in the /etc/cron.daily using the following commands:

```
sudo root vi /etc/cron.daily/fstrim
```

And fstrim file contains :

```
#! /bin/sh  

# By default we assume only / is on an SSD. 
# You can add more SSD mount points, separated by spaces.
# Make sure all mount points are within the quotes. For example:
# SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/ /boot /home /media/my_other_ssd'  

SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/mnt'  

for mount_point in $SSD_MOUNT_POINTS
do  
    fstrim $mount_point  
done
```

and then saved it and tried to run it using the command:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-16-10-56:/etc/cron.daily$ sudo /etc/cron.daily/fstrim 
fstrim: /mnt: FITRIM ioctl failed: Operation not supported
```

I get that error everytime.
I am not sure what is it that I am doing wrong.

I am following the instructions mentioned in [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Anjali

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be trying to trim `/mnt` is something mounted as `/mnt` ? usually people use `/mnt/myPartationName` most likely defined in `/etc/fstab`

---

If you are only using a single partition and you are running on a SSD change this:
`SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/mnt'`
to this:
`SSD_MOUNT_POINTS='/'`
If that is the case you could just put `fstrim /` as your cron job instead of 
that entire script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
fstrim /
```

---

Here is a SSD guide: https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/ssd

Answer (score 0):

You are likely trying to TRIM a file system which doesn't have TRIM support under linux. You can't do anything with that. What type of filesystem are you trying to TRIM?

Comment: How can we determine if a file system supports TRIM?

Comment: @AnjaliRaman You try to trim it, and if it reports that operation not supported then it is not supported. Under linux the following file systems support TRIM: Ext4, Ext3, Btrfs, FAT, GFS2, XFS, NILFS2 and OCFS2. (AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought there might be some command to see whether the directory is TRIm supported.