# fstrim for SSD in Ubuntu 15.04, --no-model-check no longer necessary?

Tags: 15.04, ssd, trim

I have SSD on my computer. before when I use Ubuntu I always do :

`sudo nano /etc/cron.weekly/fstrim`

And add this command:

`exec fstrim-all --no-model-check`

The description in this file states that "This only runs on Intel and Samsung SSDs by default", but after I install fresh Ubuntu 15.04 my file /cron.weekly/fstrim looks different. There is no info about "no-model-check" so I understand that in new version fstrim it's the default for all SSD discs, and it's not necessary to add --no-model-check?

Comment: Take a look at: https://askubuntu.com/a/19480/69296 Yes, it does perform trim support check and acts accordingly. [This comment](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/blob/master/sys-utils/fstrim.c#L224) in the source code seems to confirm that as well (disclaimer: I don't know this code. I merely analysed it for like 2 minutes = didn't analysed at all). TRIM still has problems with LUKS though.