# Are features like Trim for SSD's Included for 16.04?

Tags: kernel, ssd, trim

I am new to Ubuntu and I am wondering what to do for Sandisk SSDs? Questions I have looked up are from many years ago and I am wondering if things like Trim are now included in 16.04 and I should not really have to do anything for SSDs?

Comment: As long as you use a newer distribution like 16.04, I think you're all set. See my similar question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/864565/have-the-linux-kernel-bugs-that-caused-data-loss-when-using-a-samsung-850-pro-ss

Answer (score 2):

Yes, TRIM is now supported in the kernel and through daemons in Ubuntu. No need to worry. You can read more and check for yourself here: [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)