# Large amount of data trimmed after running fstrim

Tags: ssd, trim

Each time after I restart my computer I run fstrim. And each time this is the output I receive:

```
emil@emil-Lenovo-G580 ~> sudo fstrim -v /
[sudo] password for emil: 
/: 84.2 GiB (90372820992 bytes) trimmed
```

I want to know is this normal?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you running?  `fstrim` should automatically run by default weekly.   See [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/19480/231142).

Comment: Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. And from what i have seen I don't think that my SSD is a supported model. Or I may be wrong.

Comment: It looks as though the weekly crontab job in 14.10 and newer is just running the same command you are but on all mounted filesystems.  So my guess is that your drive is supported by it.

Comment: Also, [this page](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/12/enable-trim-ssd-better-performance/) might help shed a little more light on whether TRIM is supported or not.

Comment: You're very welcome!  =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is normal. If calling `fstrim` first time after reboot, size of all unused blocks is trimmed and reported. This is because "nobody" knows, which blocks are already trimmed before.

Calling `fstrim` again, it reports only recently freed blocks. This is, because the kernel keeps an eye to trimmed blocks. This information is lost, when rebooting.
The behavior may change between versions ...

I've watched same behavior at Debian 8 (Jessie). And wondered, as you ;-)