# No trim necessary or possible on a Ubuntu 19.10 with ZFS?

Tags: ssd, storage, zfs, trim

I've installed 19.10 with ZFS on one of my laptops because I want to learn the file system and under the impression it's "the file system of the future" (let's not discuss that here). Since I'm new and storage on my laptop is a SSD I was wondering if there's any form of trim necessary or even possible with ZFS on Ubuntu 19.10?

Comment: Trim is not related to a filesystem you are using. It is enabled by default in Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable TRIM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18903/how-to-enable-trim)

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering after having read this: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=ZFS-On-Linux-TRIM-Closer which seems to inficated that trim wasn't ready for ZFS in 2018.

Answer (score 1):

ZFS in Ubuntu 19.10 has support for trim, but I don't believe it's done by default by the periodic script/task scheduler (cron or systemd). You should either create one, or call `zpool trim [pool-name]`, and I believe there is a property where you can set autotrim, but I haven't investigated that personally. See `autotrim=on|off` in the `zpool(8)` manpage.

Comment: There are two kinds of trim: periodic and auto. The first one is done no matter of FS.